# Doc2Vec Gensim Similarity between Document and Topic

Tags: python, similarity, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying out Gensim for the first time and have a question now. I have trained a LSI Model with a corpus of prepared documents. My question is, how do i get to know if a new document is similar to my model generated from the corpus of documents. I don´t want to know the similarity for the document to each document in my corpus like MatrixSimilarity does but rather know if the document is similar to my topic/model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do LSI on new document and then Computing similarity between topics see this.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/using-lda-to-calculate-similarity/271368